# In an isomorphic flux application, should the REST api calls be implemented in the action?

Tags: reactive-programming, reactjs-flux, flux

Should it be implemented in the action creator, or in a service class or component?  Does the recommendation change if it's an isomorphic web app?

I've seen two different examples:

1. Action creator dispatches an action login_success/login_failure after making the rest call
2. Component calls an api service first and that service creates a login_success or failure action directly

### example 1

https://github.com/schempy/react-flux-api-calls

/actions/LoginActions.js

The action itself triggers a call to the api then dispatches success or failure

```
var LoginActions = {
    authenticate: function () {
        RESTApi
            .get('/api/login')
            .then(function (user) {
                   AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                     actionType: "login_success",
                     user: user
                   });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                   AppDispatcher.dispatch({actionType:"login_failure"});
            });
    };
};
```

### example 2

https://github.com/auth0/react-flux-jwt-authentication-sample

[image]

The component onclick calls an authservice function which then creates an action after it gets back the authentication results

/services/AuthService.js

```
class AuthService {

  login(username, password) {
    return this.handleAuth(when(request({
      url: LOGIN_URL,
      method: 'POST',
      crossOrigin: true,
      type: 'json',
      data: {
        username, password
      }
    })));
  }

  logout() {
    LoginActions.logoutUser();
  }

  signup(username, password, extra) {
    return this.handleAuth(when(request({
      url: SIGNUP_URL,
      method: 'POST',
      crossOrigin: true,
      type: 'json',
      data: {
        username, password, extra
      }
    })));
  }

  handleAuth(loginPromise) {
    return loginPromise
      .then(function(response) {
        var jwt = response.id_token;
        LoginActions.loginUser(jwt);
        return true;
      });
  }
}
```

What's the better/standard place for this call to live in a Flux architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I use an api.store with an api utility. From https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/ReFluxSuperAgent.

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import ApiFct from './../utils/api.js';

let ApiStoreObject = {
 newData: {
  "React version": "0.14",
  "Project": "ReFluxSuperAgent",
  "currentDateTime": new Date().toLocaleString()
 },
 listenables: Actions,
 apiInit() { ApiFct.setData(this.newData); },
 apiInitDone() { ApiFct.getData(); },
 apiSetData(data) { ApiFct.setData(data); }
}
const ApiStore = Reflux.createStore(ApiStoreObject);
export default ApiStore;
```

```js
import request from 'superagent';

import Actions from '../flux/Actions';

let uri = 'http://localhost:3500';

module.exports = {
 getData() { request.get(uri + '/routes/getData').end((err, res) => { this.gotData(res.body); }); },
 gotData(data) { Actions.gotData1(data); Actions.gotData2(data); Actions.gotData3(data); },
 setData(data) { request.post('/routes/setData').send(data).end((err, res) => { Actions.apiInitDone(); }) },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is better to use option 1:

- Putting API calls in an action creator instead of component lets you better separate concerns: your component(-tree) only calls a "log me in" action, and can remain ignorant about where the response comes from. Could in theory come from the store if login details are already known.
- Calls to the API are more centralized in the action, and therefore more easily debugged.

Option 2 looks like it still fits with the flux design principles.

There are also advocates of a third alternative: call the webAPI from the store. This makes close coupling of data structures on server and client side easier/ more compartmental. And may work better if syncing *independent* data structures between client and server is a key concern. My experiences have not been positive with third option: having stores (indirectly) create actions breaks the unidirectional flux pattern. Benefits for me never outweighed the extra troubles in debugging. But your results may vary.